# How to know margin-left auto pixels from the left side?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery mousemove to follow cursor by image (I am doing this for only one div). I have centered whole page (margin-left: auto ; margin-right: auto;). But here comes problem:

```
$('.friendSelection').mousemove(function(e){
                $('.follow').show();
                $(".follow").css({left:e.pageX-690, top:e.pageY-30});});
```

that e.pageX is giving not main div's x axis, but whole page x axis(and image is really far away from cursor). And now if user has bigger screen, then I have to know how much pixels, margin-left auto had moved whole page, to change cursor position ( $(".follow").css({left:e.pageX-690, top:e.pageY-30}) ). Any Ideas?

P.S. my html code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="mainBody">
<div class="friendSelection">
<div class="friend" id="1"></div>
<div class="friend" id="2"></div>
<div class="friend" id="3"></div>
</div>
<div class="follow"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Those friend classes are always falling from top to bottom, this is problem that my follow image is 115x185px and when mouse move, image follows it, but if mouse is moving in whole image then image don't follow cursor

Comment: Any luck with this? Posted my answer below :)

Comment: Thanks for answer VIDesignz, but still some problems :/ I added my HTML code

Comment: Can you post a link to the page you are working on? I'd like to see it in action to get a better idea of what you are going for.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "if mouse is moving in whole image then image don't follow cursor" ??

Comment: I mean if mouse move in image size (115x185) then that image isn't following the mouse, but when cursor leaves image then image again is on cursor. Here is mine page: http://spark.outsourcers.dk/index3.php . And could you see that image is far away from cursor, while in facebook everything is ok. I am using code which I posted in my main post.

Comment: I think I know what you are saying... try putting this in your .css for the the .follow element {pointer-events:none;}

Comment: This helped, but I have now problem that cursor is lagging :/ instead of fadein fadeout I made hide and show. In fireox and safari everything is ok, but in IE and Chrome cursor is lagging, maybe have ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I wish I could tell you for sure, I believe those two browsers are much slower when processing JavaScript. And since the mousemove function is continuously running, it may lag a bit when this function is running.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead...

Here is a working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/7a6qS/)

```
$("body").on({

    mousemove: function(e){
         $('.follow').fadeIn(500).css({'left' : e.pageX, 'top' : e.pageY});
     },

    mouseout: function(e){
         $('.follow').fadeOut(500);
     }

}, ".friendSelection" );
```

You can also place the '.follow' element centered on the cursor, and use this function for multiple '.friendSelection' elements.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/7a6qS/2/)